# Why Question about "US demonetize large bills" was closed

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, vote-to-close

I have a question [Could the US demonetize large bills? If so, how can I protect myself if I rely on holding US dollars in cash?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/107317/)
Is there a way to reopen this question.

Till "April 08" is was shown on hold and later it shows as closed as of April 03. So second question is about dates being shown as incorrect.

I understand that sites does not want to show the voters names, but at least the asker be allowed to see the vote count for + and -.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You posted this meta question about 8 minutes after the original question was reopened.

You asked it on April 3rd and it was closed same day, as off topic.

April 7 is when the votes to reopen started.

It takes a rep of 250 to see reopen votes on your own question, and 1000 rep to see votes +/- on questions and answers. See [Help Center > Privileges](https://money.stackexchange.com/help/privileges)

I believe this meta question is a bit late and moot, as the discussion regarding the OT issue was all discussed in the comments on the question itself. You can edit this question if you wish to clarify.

Comment: Is there a way to see the deleted comments in the original post ?

Comment: @Neil only moderators can see deleted comments.